# Emulating -ErrorAction in custom powershell function

Tags: powershell

How to emulate -ErrorAction in custom powershell function. For example consider the following script

```
function Foo2
{
  Write-Host "in Foo2"
  #...Error occurs 
  Foo3
}

function Foo1
{
   Write-Host "in Foo1"
   Foo2
}

function Foo3
{
   Write-Host "in Foo3"
}
```

PS>Foo1 -ErrorAction stop

Is it possible to stop the execution of Foo1 when error occurs in Foo2, instead of proceeding with execution of Foo3 ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`get-help about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute`

You want:

```
function Foo1() {
 [CmdletBinding()]
 PARAM()
 process{
   Write-Host "in Foo1"
   Foo2
 }
}
```

This is not about *emulation*, it means really implementing common parameters in your function; if this was your intention.

---

After that, you can work like this:

```
Foo1 -ErrorAction stop
```

You can use the same syntax for `Foo2` and `Foo3`.

---

To log error use redirection as usual.

Comment: let me make it clear, just like how standard cmdlet will stop or continue when error occurs based on value of ErrorAction , I want even Foo1 to behave exactly like that also i would like to log the error. How can i do that ?

Comment: If you use `cmdletbinding` you can do exactly that gratis! See my edit.

Comment: Small note, the `Write-Error` calls or errors from nested commands will use that, `Write-Host` will not.  :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sample to illustrate @Empo Answer

```
function Test-ErrorAction
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param( )

  begin 
  {
    Write-Host "I'am Here"    
   }

  Process 
  {
    Write-Error "coucou"
  }
  end 
  {
    Write-Host "Done !"
  }
}

clear
Test-ErrorAction -ErrorAction "silentlycontinue"
Test-ErrorAction -ErrorAction "stop"
```

gives

```
I'am Here
Done !
I'am Here
coucou
 à C:\Développements\Pgdvlp_Powershell\Sources partagées\Menus Contextuel Explorer\Test-ErrorAction.ps1: ligne:23 caractère:17
+ Test-ErrorAction  <<<< -ErrorAction "stop"
```

Comment: NB: It's also worth noting that for `ErrorAction` to behave as you'd expect, you should raise errors with `Write-Error`.  If you `throw` an exception, `ErrorAction` / `ErrorActionPreference` has no influence; the exception is a `Stop` (terminating error) by definition.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295344/361842

Answer (score 0):

```
function Foo2
{
 Write-Host "in Foo2"
 Try {something} 
   Catch {
             Write-host "Foo2 blew up!"
             return
             }
 Foo3
 }
```