# When should I use Write-Error vs. Throw? Terminating vs. non-terminating errors

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-2.0

Looking at a Get-WebFile script over on PoshCode, http://poshcode.org/3226, I noticed this strange-to-me contraption:

```
$URL_Format_Error = [string]"..."
Write-Error $URL_Format_Error
return
```

What is the reason for this as opposed to the following?

```
$URL_Format_Error = [string]"..."
Throw $URL_Format_Error
```

Or even better:

```
$URL_Format_Error = New-Object System.FormatException "..."
Throw $URL_Format_Error
```

As I understand, you should use Write-Error for non-terminating errors, and Throw for terminating errors, so it seems to me that you should not use Write-Error followed by Return. Is there a difference?

Comment: What do you mean? If Write_error allows the script to continue it is very understandable to have a return statement after Write-Error. The error has been written out and you return back to the code that called the function in the first place. Since Throw is for terminating errors it will terminate automatically so that a return statement in a throw declaration is useless

Comment: @Gisli: It's important to note that `return` does _not_ return to the caller in the `process` block of an (advanced) function; instead, it proceeds to the _next input object_ in the pipeline. Indeed, this is the typical scenario for generating non-terminating errors: if processing further input objects is still possible.

Comment: Note that `Throw` generates a _script_-terminating error, which is not the same as the _statement_-terminating errors triggered, for instance, by `Get-Item -NoSuchParameter` or `1 / 0`.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

`Write-Error` should be used if you want to inform the user of a non-critical error. By default all it does is print an error message in red text on the console. It does not stop a pipeline or a loop from continuing. `Throw` on the other hand produces what is called a terminating error. If you use throw, the pipeline and/or current loop will be terminated. In fact all execution will be terminated unless you use a `trap` or a `try/catch` structure to handle the terminating error.

There is one thing to note, if you set **`$ErrorActionPreference` to `"Stop"`** and use `Write-Error` it will **produce a terminating error**.

In the script you linked to we find this:

```
if ($url.Contains("http")) {
       $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
}
else {
       $URL_Format_Error = [string]"Connection protocol not specified. Recommended action: Try again using protocol (for example 'http://" + $url + "') instead. Function aborting..."
       Write-Error $URL_Format_Error
    return
   }
```

It looks like the author of that function wanted to stop the execution of that function and display an error message on screen but did not want the entire script to stop executing. The script author could have used `throw` however it would mean you would have to use a `try/catch` when calling the function.

`return` will exit the current scope which can be a function, script, or script block. This is best illustrated with code:

```
# A foreach loop.
foreach ( $i in  (1..10) ) { Write-Host $i ; if ($i -eq 5) { return } }

# A for loop.
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) { Write-Host $i ; if ($i -eq 5) { return } }
```

Output for both:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

One gotcha here is using `return` with `ForEach-Object`. It will not break processing like one might expect.

More information:

- `$ErrorActionPreference`: *[about_Preference_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347731.aspx)*
- `try/catch`: *[about_Try_Catch_Finally](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315350.aspx)*
- `trap`: *[about_Trap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347548.aspx)*
- `throw`: *[about_Throw](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819510.aspx)*
- `return`: *[about_Return](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347592.aspx)*

Comment: Ok, so Throw will stop everything, Write-Error + return will stop only the current function.

Comment: @BillBarry I updated my answer a bit with an explanation of `return`.

Comment: What about Write-Error followed by exit(1) to ensure appropriate error code returned to OS?  Is that ever appropriate?

Answer (score 40):

**Important**: There are ***two* types of terminating errors**, which the current help topics unfortunately *conflate*:

- ***statement*-terminating** errors, as reported by cmdlets in certain non-recoverable situations and by expressions in which a .NET exception / a PS runtime error occurs; only the *statement* is terminated, and *script execution continues by default*.
- ***script*-terminating** errors (more accurately: ***runspace*-terminating**) or, pragmatically speaking, ***fatal* (by default) errors**, as either triggered by the [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement or by *escalating* one of the other error types via the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction), namely 
  `-ErrorAction Stop`, or via the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference), namely `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.
  Unless caught, they terminate the current runspace (thread); that is, they terminate not just the current script, but all its callers too, if applicable.

For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling, see [GitHub documentation issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

The remainder of this post focuses on *non-terminating* vs. *statement-terminating* errors.

---

To complement the existing helpful answers with a focus on the core of the question: **How do you *choose* whether to report a statement-*terminating* or *non-terminating* error**?

[Cmdlet Error Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-error-reporting) contains helpful guidelines; let me attempt a **pragmatic summary**:

**The general idea behind *non-terminating* errors is to allow "fault-tolerant" processing of large input sets**: failure to process a *subset* of the input objects should not (by default) abort the - potentially long-running - process *as a whole*, allowing you to inspect the errors and **reprocess only the *failed* objects *later*** - as reported via the error records collected in the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error).

- Report a **NON-TERMINATING** error, if your cmdlet / advanced function:

  - **accepts MULTIPLE input objects**, via the pipeline input and/or array-valued parameters, AND
  - **errors occur for SPECIFIC input objects**, AND
  - **these errors DO NOT PREVENT PROCESSING of FURTHER input objects IN PRINCIPLE** (*situationally*, there may be no input objects left and/or previous input objects may already have been processed successfully).

    - In advanced functions, use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` to report a non-terminating error (`Write-Error`, unfortunately, doesn't cause `$?` to be set to `$False` in the *caller's* scope - see [GitHub issue #3629](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3629)).
    - *Handling* a non-terminating error: `$?` tells you whether the most recent command reported *at least one* non-terminating error.

      - Thus, `$?` being `$False` can either mean that *any (nonempty) subset* of input objects weren't properly processed, possibly the entire set.
      - Preference variable `$ErrorActionPreference` and/or common cmdlet parameter `-ErrorAction` can modify the behavior of non-terminating errors (only) in terms of error output behavior and whether non-terminating errors should be escalated to *script*-terminating ones.
- Report a **STATEMENT-TERMINATING** error in **all other cases**.

  - Notably, **if an error occurs in a cmdlet / advanced function that only accepts a SINGLE or NO input object and outputs NO or a SINGLE output object or takes *parameter input only* and the parameter values given prevent meaningful operation.**

    - In advanced functions, you must use `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` in order to generate a statement-terminating error.
    - Note that, by contrast, the `Throw` keyword generates a *script*-terminating error that aborts the *entire script* (technically: the current *runspace* (thread)).
    - *Handling* a statement-terminating error: A `try/catch` handler or `trap` statement may be used (which *cannot* be used with *non-terminating* errors), but note that even *statement*-terminating errors by default do not prevent the rest of the script from running. As with *non-terminating* errors, `$?` reflects `$False` if the previous statement triggered a statement-terminating error.

---

**Not all of PowerShell's own built-in cmdlets play by these rules**:

- [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) inappropriately reports a *statement-terminating* error when any one of the names passed to the  `-Name` parameter doesn't refer to an existing registry value, up to at least PowerShell (Core) v7.3.4 - see [GitHub issue #5906](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5906)
- While unlikely to fail, [`New-TemporaryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-temporaryfile) (PSv5+) would report a non-terminating error if it failed, despite not accepting pipeline input and only producing only *one* output object - this has been corrected as of at least PowerShell (Core) 7.0, however: see [GitHub issue #4634](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4634).
- [`Resume-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/resume-job) 's help claims that passing an unsupported job type (such as a job created with `Start-Job`, which is not supported, because `Resume-Job` only applies to *workflow* jobs) causes a terminating error, but that's not true as of PSv5.1.

Answer (score 21):

The main difference between the [Write-Error](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315265.aspx) cmdlet and the [throw](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819510.aspx) keyword in PowerShell is that the former simply **prints** some text to the [standard error stream (stderr)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29), while the latter actually **terminates** the processing of the running command or function, which is *then* handled by PowerShell by sending out information about the error to the console.

You can observe the different behavior of the two in the examples you provided:

```
$URL_Format_Error = [string]"..."
Write-Error $URL_Format_Error
return
```

In this example the `return` keyword has been added to *explicitly* stop the execution of the script after the error message has been sent out to the console. In the second example, on the other hand, the `return` keyword is not necessary since termination is implicitly done by `throw`:

```
$URL_Format_Error = New-Object System.FormatException "..."
Throw $URL_Format_Error
```

Comment: if you have $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop", Write-Error  will also terminate the process.

Comment: Good info, but while PowerShell's error stream is _analogous_ to the _text-based_ stderr stream in other shells, like all PowerShell streams it contains _objects_, namely `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances,
 which are by default collected in the automatic `$Error` collection (`$Error[0]` contains the most recent error). Even if you just use `Write-Error` with a _string_, that string gets wrapped in a `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instance.

Answer (score 12):

**Addition to [Andy Arismendi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294949/when-should-i-use-write-error-vs-throw-terminating-vs-non-terminating-errors/9295344#9295344):**

Whether [Write-Error](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315265.aspx)  terminates the process or not depends on the `$ErrorActionPreference` setting.

For non-trivial scripts, `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` is a [recommended setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948517/how-to-stop-a-powershell-script-on-the-first-error) to fail fast.

> "PowerShell’s default behaviour with respect to errors, which is to
>   continue on error ...feels very VB6 “On Error Resume Next”-ish"

(from http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2010/02/25/the-exec-problem/)

However, it makes `Write-Error` calls terminating.

To use [Write-Error](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315265.aspx) as a non-terminating command regardless of other environment settings, you can use [common parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx) `-ErrorAction` with value `Continue`:

```
 Write-Error "Error Message" -ErrorAction:Continue
```

Answer (score 8):

`Write-Error` allows the consumer of the function to suppress the error message with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (alternatively `-ea 0`). While `throw` requires a `try{...} catch {..}`

To use a try...catch with `Write-Error`:

```
try {
    SomeFunction -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    DoSomething
}
```

Comment: Why you need to call Write-Error at all, if you want to suppress the error message ?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Instead of the hardcoded -ErrorAction Stop like in this example, you can also use a variable (the builtin $ErrorActionPreference, or one of your own).
In that way the user or the programmer has more control over the handling of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If your reading of the code is correct then you are correct.  Terminating errors should use `throw`, and if you're dealing with .NET types then it is helpful to also follow .NET exception conventions.