# What's the difference between the "throw" keyword and "Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop"?

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble googling up a clear answer on this. Are there any practical differences between, for example, `throw 'temper tantrum'` and `Write-Error 'temper tantrum' -ErrorAction Stop`?

They both generate terminating errors and set $? to False. I can see that there are differences in the CategoryInfo and FullyQualifiedErrorId. The operative word is *practical*. Do they have any different effects? Are there reasons to prefer one over the other in particular situations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use Write-Error vs Throw?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294949/when-should-i-use-write-error-vs-throw)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. My question is more specific. The main difference between **Write-Error** and **throw** is that **throw** generates a terminating error, and **Write-Error** by default does not. I was already aware of that. My question was specifically whether there are any differences in functionality if "-ErrorAction Stop" is used to make Write-Error generate a terminating error. I now see (due to the hint in Ansgar's answer) that they populate $error with different object types. What I'd like to know is whether there are any pros, cons, caveats, or different uses between the two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`throw` generates a terminating error, `Write-Error` without `-ErrorAction Stop` would generate a non-terminating error. Since `-ErrorAction Stop` turns the non-terminating into a terminating error, the two instructions are basically the same.

There are differences, though. `throw <expression>` populates `$error[0].TargetObject` with `<expression>`, while `Write-Error <expression> -ErrorAction Stop` does not.

Comment: That does point me in a direction, though it seems rather confusing. I see that in fact there are a lot of differences in the way $error gets populated, apparently because **throw** unshifts an ErrorRecord object onto the $error array, whereas **Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop** unshifts an ActionPreferenceStopException object. Oddly enough, though, when **Write-Error** creates a *non*-terminating error, it adds an ErrorRecord object to $error. So, back to my emphasis on the word "practical": in what kinds of situations would either one be more suitable or have different behavior than the other?

Comment: In fact, from what I'm reading at MSDN, apparently the error generated by **Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop** technically isn't even a terminating error, though it does terminate the script (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.errorrecord%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.actionpreferencestopexception%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Still wondering if there are any practical differences in use because of this.

Comment: This would be far from the first time someone found multiple different ways to do the same thing in PowerShell.  :-)  Using `throw` is the canonical way to express terminating errors and `Write-Error` is the canonical way to express non-terminating errors (doh that one file out of 1000 is in use - I'll note a non-terminating error but continue processing the other 999).  It is really just by virtue that all cmdlets implement the ubiquitous parameter -ErrorAction that this corner case (Write-Error -ea Stop) exists.

Comment: @AdiInbar I would always use `throw` for generating a terminating error. Not only is it shorter, but it's also a syntax well-known from other languages, and it's more self-explanatory with respect to what it does. I'd use `Write-Error` only for what its name suggests: to write error messages to the error stream.

Comment: @KeithHill Good point - in fact, that explains the oddness I commented above: using **-ea Stop** with Write-Error does terminate the script, but I guess it's not really there as part of the intended behavior of Write-Error, it's there because it's a common parameter, and actually circumvents the intended behavior of Write-Error. However, what I like about using `Write-Error -ea Stop` is that it lets you set the error category. Also, it lets you define the entire ErrorRecord object. Is there anyway to create a genuine terminating error and also control ErrorRecord and Category?

Comment: @AdiInbar Yes. If you're writing an advanced function, you can (and should) use `$pscmdlet.WriteError()` which takes an ErrorRecord that you create. You can then specify the Category, etc.

Comment: You can also construct an exception, for example `Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException` and an errorrecord `Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`, link them together, fill out whatever fields you want and throw the exception you created.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I was hoping to get some examples like "'throw' works best if you're trying to do such-and-such, but 'Write-Error' is more effective if you're trying to do this-and-that, because..." - that's what I mean by *practical* differences. I'll accept this answer since it pointed me in a direction that helped me understand the difference in how they operate, and improve the way I handle errors in my scripts. But if anyone can think of any practical examples of where one works better than the other for a particular purpose, please add more answers, and I'll upvote them. Thanks!