# Powershell script stops on exception caught in try/catch block; $ErrorActionPreference

Tags: powershell

Problem: powershell script stops because of an exception which should be caught by the try block when using $ErrorActionPreference

Example:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    ThisCommandWillThrowAnException
} catch {
    Write-Error 'Caught an Exception'
}
# this line is not executed. 
Write-Output 'Continuing execution'
```

Answer (score 7):

Solution: `Write-Error` actually throws a non-terminating exception by default. When `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is set, `Write-Error` throws a terminating exception within the catch block.

Override this using `-ErrorAction 'Continue'`

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    ThisCommandWillThrowAnException
} catch {
    Write-Error 'Caught an Exception' -ErrorAction 'Continue'
}
# this line is now executed as expected
Write-Output 'Continuing execution'
```

Comment: Also see Andy Arismendi's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294949/when-should-i-use-write-error-vs-throw