# Possible to specify error Type using Write-Error, or only with throw?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, powershell-5.0

I am building a script that will have a [Try statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315350.aspx) with `Try` block and multiple `Catch` blocks. [This page has provided a good guide to help with identifying error types](https://learn-powershell.net/2015/04/09/quick-hits-finding-exception-types-with-powershell/) in PowerShell, and how to handle them in `catch` statements.

I've been using [`Write-Error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error) up till now. I thought one of the optional parameters (`Category` or `CategoryTargetType`) could be used to specify the error type, and then a `catch` block used specifically for that type.

No luck: the type is always listed as `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException`.
`throw` gives me exactly what I'm after.

**Code**

```
[CmdletBinding()]param()

Function Do-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    Write-Error "something happened" -Category InvalidData
}

try{
    Write-host "running Do-Something..."
    Do-Something -ErrorAction Stop

}catch [System.IO.InvalidDataException]{ # would like to catch write-error here
    Write-Host "1 caught"
}catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException]{ # it's caught here
    Write-host "1 kind of caught" 
}catch{
    Write-Host "1 not caught properly: $($Error[0].exception.GetType().fullname)"
}


Function Do-SomethingElse {
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    throw  [System.IO.InvalidDataException] "something else happened"
}

try{
    Write-host "`nrunning Do-SomethingElse..."
    Do-SomethingElse -ErrorAction Stop

}catch [System.IO.InvalidDataException]{  # caught here, as wanted
    Write-Host "2 caught"
}catch{
    Write-Host "2 not caught properly: $($Error[0].exception.GetType().fullname)"
}
```

**Output**

```
running Do-Something...
1 kind of caught

running Do-SomethingElse...
2 caught
```

My code is doing what I want; it doesn't have to be `Write-Error` when `throw` does the job. What I'd like to understand is:

- Is it possible to specify a Type with `Write-Error` (or in some other way differentiate between `Write-Error` errors) so that they can be handled in different **`catch`** blocks?

<sub>N.B. I am aware that `$Error[1] -like "something happen*"` and handle using `if`/`else` blocks is an option.</sub>

<sub>[Closest related question I could find on SO - `Write-Error` v `throw` in terminating/non-terminating context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294949/when-should-i-use-write-error-vs-throw-terminating-vs-non-terminating-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the -Exception Parameter to specify the exception type to throw from Write-Error, see example below (PS5) or Example 4 of Get-Help Write-Error:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Error

```
try { 
    Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop -Exception ([System.OutOfMemoryException]::new())  } 
catch [System.OutOfMemoryException] { 
    "Just system.OutOfMemoryException"
} catch {
    "Other exceptions"
}
```