# How to handle failed variable assignments in powershell?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am trying to handle setting a PowerShell variable from a registry key.

So I use a `try{} catch {}` to get rid of eventual errors in case the key doesn't exists. However, I still get the error output on console.

```bsh
$ZZ_ConVTL = try { (Get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Console" -name VirtualTerminalLevel).VirtualTerminalLevel } catch { "N/A" }

...

# Output:
Get-ItemProperty : Property VirtualTerminalLevel does not exist at path HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\xxxx\xxxx.ps1:181 char:32
+ ...    = try { (Get-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Console" -name VirtualTermi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (VirtualTerminalLevel:String) [Get-ItemProperty], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

**How can I handle and avoid this error from showing up in the console?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What your `Get-ItemProperty` call emits is a *non-terminating* error, whereas `try` / `catch` only catches *terminating* errors.**

- Non-terminating errors are far more common that terminating ones.

**Use [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) `-ErrorAction Stop`** to promote (the first) non-terminating error generated by a cmdlet to a terminating one that `try` / `catch` handles.

You can generally achieve the same effect by setting **preference variable**
**`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`** beforehand, but note that doing so has *no* effect on functions implemented in script *modules*.

---

See also:

- The [`about_Try_Catch_Finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) help topic.
- A description of the **fundamental error types** in the context of guidance for command authors on when to emit a terminating vs. a non-terminating error: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).
- A **comprehensive overview** of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling: [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).