# Try/Catch Statements don't seem to be working

Tags: function, powershell, error-handling, try-catch

Afternoon!

**EDIT**

After some more troubleshooting, I've noticed it doesn't seem to want to catch the error from the `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path Z:\PMO\PMOBits\test` section. If I put in a *Null* value, it catches that error in both my `Get-Logger` function and using `Write-output`. *Why wouldn't it catch the Folder already exists error?*

I'm have a logging function in my PowerShell script and I'm trying to incorporate some error handling using this function. Below is the logging function.

```
Function Get-Logger { 
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [String]$message,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
       [validatescript({[enum]::getvalues([system.consolecolor]) -contains $_})][string]$Color
    )

    $TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyy hh:mm:ss"

    Write-Host $TimeStamp -NoNewline
    IF ($Color) {
        Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor $($color)
    } Else {
        Write-Host `t $message -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
    $logMessage = "[$TimeStamp]  $message"
    $logMessage | Out-File -Append -LiteralPath $VerboseLogFile
}
```

I'm testing this with some simple code for the error handling, see the test code below.

```
Try { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path Z:\PMO\PMOBits\test } 
    Catch {
        Get-Logger "ERROR: This file already exists"
    }
```

When I run the script, I see the error populate on the terminal that it already exists, but It's not showing in my log file like the `catch` section should do.

I've also tried to catch the error without using my function below:

```
try{...}
catch {
Write-Output $_ | Out-File -Append -LiteralPath $VerboseLogFile
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-ErrorAction Stop` with your `New-Item` statement.

```
    Try { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path Z:\PMO\PMOBits\test -ErrorAction Stop } 
    Catch {
        Get-Logger "ERROR: This file already exists"
    }
```

Comment: @Fitzgery, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641995/45375) for background information; Jawad, variations of this problem keep coming up, and I encourage you to vote for closure as a duplicate in the future.