# Error not caught in PowerShell try/catch/finally if not thrown explicitly

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to fetch a file using *Get-SCPFile* from the [Posh-SSH module](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH) and when such a file doesn't exists, an error is thrown. I want to catch said error and attempt the operation with a different file name.

```
try {
  Write-Host "Primary attempt with" $target
  # throw "up"
  Get-SCPFile -RemoteFile ($origin + $target + ".csv") ...
}
catch {
  $target = $target -replace "1$", "2"
  Write-Host "Secondary attempt with" $target
  Get-SCPFile -RemoteFile ($origin + $target + ".csv") ...
}
finally {
  Write-Host "Final action performed with" $target
}
```

For some reason, when the file doesn't exist, I get to *finally* and the screen shows red error but the *catch* part is omitted. However, when I activate my *throw up*, the exception is caught as expected and the statement in *catch* executes.

Googling along the lines of *PS error not caught* gave me a very widespread and uninformative results.

I omitted the exact call for brevity reasons since the invokation as such seems to work properly but for the curious reader (and in case I'm missing a relevant detail), here it is.

```
Get-SCPFile -ComputerName $server 
            -Credential $credential 
            -RemoteFile ($origin + $target + ".csv") 
            -LocalFile ($destination + $target + ".csv")
```

Optimally, I'd also like to test the existence of the file **prior** to actually fetching it. However, the package I'm using only has [documentation](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/tree/master/docs) on [Test-SFTP](https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Test-SFTPPath.md), not Test-SCP. Also, even more importantly in this context, the question of the uncaught exception is the main subject.

Comment: In short: `try` / `catch` only acts on _terminating_ errors, whereas it is far more typical for cmdlets to report _non-terminating_ errors. For the `catch` block to get invoked, non-terminating errors must be promoted to terminating ones by passing `-ErrorAction Stop` or by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` beforehand. See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641995/45375) for more information.

Comment: Your question - which is much better formulated than the first linked duplicate (I've since added another duplicate that better resembles yours in wording and problem statement) - will continue to remain discoverable, and the duplicate notice at the top is a clear signal to future readers that they need to go elsewhere for the solution. To help them, I've posted my comment with a succinct summary, plus a direct link to the relevant _answer_ (in my estimation). If we were to reopen your question, it would call for the very same answer as the linked one, and for that reason it is a duplicate.