# Get-AdUser Lookup for each user in csv list with LDAPFilter anr match

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I'm querying AD for user details using a list of usernames derived from a different list meaning that not all usernames match the SamAccountName exactly e.g. might have a number or letter dropped from the end. I can get the exact match lookup to work and output the names it can't find but I'd like to take that list names and run them through an LDAPFilter anr search to check for fuzzy matches as well. So far I have:

```
ForEach($User in $List){
Write-host "Now checking $User"

Try{
     Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$User)" -Properties * | 
     select-object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,mail,Enabled | 
     Export-CSV -Append $OutputFileResults -NoTypeInformation
     Write-host "$User found successfully" -foregroundcolor Green
     }
Catch{
    $User | Export-CSV -Append $OutputFileFailed -NoTypeInformation
    Write-host "$User not found" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
}
```

At the moment the output I get just says that the username was found successfully but writes nothing into the output file.

Comment: You could also go about creating a LDAPFitler for all users and query all of them at once, that would remove the need of a `try catch` and also `if`.

Comment: Thank you everyone all of those answers worked. I was also making life difficult because I was using a .csv list input but the user names started with a hyphen so an apostrophe was inserted before each username. I switched to .txt input and that resolved it.

Comment: In general: `try` / `catch` only acts on _terminating_ errors, whereas it is far more typical for cmdlets to report _non-terminating_ errors. For the `catch` block to get invoked, non-terminating errors must be promoted to terminating ones by passing `-ErrorAction Stop` or by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` beforehand. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641995/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter ...` doesn't throw an exception when no users are found, so the fact that is says the username was found tells you nothing - it would have told you that whether it found 0 or 100 :)

Explicitly test whether it actually returns anything to make it work:

```
ForEach($User in $List){
    Write-host "Now checking $User"

    Try {
        # search for matching users
        $matchingUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$User)" -Properties * |
            Select-object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,mail,Enabled

        if(-not $matchingUsers){
            # no users found? throw to enter the catch block
            throw
        }
        # otherwise proceed to export to CSV
        $matching |Export-CSV -Append $OutputFileResults -NoTypeInformation
        Write-host "$User found successfully" -foregroundcolor Green
    }
    Catch {
        $User | Export-CSV -Append $OutputFileFailed -NoTypeInformation
        Write-host "$User not found" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try/Catch in not necessarily always the best way to handle checks to see if objects were returned.  Personally I would use an if/else statement instead.  In the `if` condition we assign the result of Get-ADUser to `$matchedUsers` and then check if that is empty or not.  If it is not empty then we continue into the `if` block.  If `$matchedUsers` is empty then the `else` block is run.

```
ForEach ($User in $List) {
    Write-Host "Now checking $User"

    if ($matchedUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$User)" -Properties *) {
        $matchedUsers | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, mail, Enabled |
            Export-Csv -Append $OutputFileResults -NoTypeInformation

        Write-Host "$User found successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
    } 
    else {
        $User | Export-Csv -Append $OutputFileFailed -NoTypeInformation
        Write-Host "$User not found" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```