# Silence / Redirect PowerShell error stream: what am I missing?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a Powershell script to loosen the execution policy on a machine, essentially running:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`

Since ExecutionPolicy is restriced on the machine, I need to launch the .ps1 script using .bat file which bypasses the execution policy like this:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ./psscripts/myScript.ps1
```

By using this trick, I get the following error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of Bypass.
```

The error is trying to tell me that policy scope of the current process (launched with -Bypass) overrides the one I just set, but I don´t really care anyway, so I would like to simply hide this error.

I have tried using the -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

But the error still displays. So I tried to redirect the error stream to &NULL like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force 2> $NULL
```

...but even like this, the error still pops up on the terminal.

I have successfully managed to silence the error using a try-catch like this:

```
try{Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force} catch {}
```

However, I would still like to understand why the two other approaches won´t work?
Trying to redirect the error stream (or *any* stream) to a variable, the variable turns out empty, so I assume I am somehow trying to redirect the stream from the wrong process?
Does this have something to do with launching Powershell from the .bat file?

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Redirecting PowerShell's [error output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) with `2>` only works for *non-terminating* errors**.

<sup>Note: The [`-ErrorAction` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) operates exclusively on *non-terminating* errors as well - *unlike* the seemingly equivalent [`ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference), however, which - surprisingly - also applies to *terminating* errors - see the link to the GitHub docs issue below.</sup>

**`Set-ExecutionPolicy` emits a *terminating* error**, which only [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) can handle (and the rarely used [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement).

See also:

- A description of **PowerShell's fundamental error types** in the context of guidance for command authors on when to emit a terminating vs. a non-terminating error: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).
- A **comprehensive overview** of PowerShell's surprisingly complex **error handling**: [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

Comment: Thanks, this made things clearer. The difference between "statement terminating" and "script terminating" was not too clear to me, and since the script was continuing I assumed the error was non-terminating.

The reason why "Set-ExecutionPolicy" emits a terminating error for something that might as well be a simple warning (the execution policy gets changed after all) still escapes me, but this is a whole other matter.