# Powershell Write-Output of array goes missing if error thrown afterwards

Tags: powershell

Right so in Powershell if you Write-Output some lines and then throw an error, you'd expect to get the output that happens before the error. So if you execute this:

```
Write-Output ("test output 1")
Write-Output ("test output 2")
Write-Output ("test output 3")
Write-Output ("test output 4")
Write-Output ("test output 5")
throw "pretend error"
```

You will get this as expected:

```
test output 1
test output 2
test output 3
test output 4
test output 5
pretend error
At C:\Powershell\Test.ps1:7 char:1
+ throw "pretend error"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (pretend error:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : pretend error
```

However if you Write-Output a bunch of objects in an array, and then afterwards throw an error, the Write-Output of the array (and anything after that) never appears. So if you run this:

```
Write-Output ("test output 1")
Write-Output ("test output 2")
Write-Output ("test output 3")
Write-Output ("test output 4")
Write-Output ("test output 5")
$testlist = @()
$count = 1
While($count -lt 6)
{
    $testobj = new-object psobject -prop @{Name="array object $count"}
    $testlist += $testobj
    $count +=1
}
Write-Output $testlist 
Write-Output ("test output 6")
Write-Output ("test output 7")
throw "pretend error"
```

... you dont get any of the output after "test output 5". Its as if outputting the array makes everything get buffered and then the error loses the buffer. Something to do with the way Powershell uses pipes with arrays?

So my question is: what do I need to do to make sure the Write-Output doesn't get **lost** due to subsequent errors. This makes logging really difficult.

This is in Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're seeing a **very unfortunate side effect of the problematic 300-millisecond delay that was introduced to *implicit* use of [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) in PowerShell v5** in order to better calculate suitable column widths, which is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) and discussed in [GitHub issue #4594](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594); however, your symptom is so problematic that it warrants a **new bug report**: [GitHub issue #13985](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13985).

Because your `$testlist` array contains objects that have *fewer than `4` properties* (namely just one in your case) and because the type of your objects (`[pscustomobject]`) has *no formatting data* associated with it, PowerShell *implicitly* uses `Format-Table` for output formatting.

By the time the `throw` statement is encountered, the 300-millisecond delay has not elapsed yet, and because `throw` terminates the runspace<sup>[1]</sup>, the `Format-Table` output (and the subsequent `Write-Output` output) are never shown.

The - **imperfect** - **workaround** is to **force output to be *synchronous***, which can be done with one of three ways:

- Use `Out-Host`, which uses the default output behavior *synchronously*, but it also means that *from inside PowerShell* you won't be able to capture or redirect the output; however, *when called from the outside, via PowerShell's CLI*, `Out-Host` output goes to stdout and can be captured too.
- Use `Format-Table` *explicitly*. This also works fine for display, but changes the output from your *data* to *unrelated objects that are formatting instructions*, which PowerShell itself translates to the usual, rich display formatting, but these are useless if you wanted to *capture* the output - your original data is lost.
- If you want to least allow capturing the *formatted string representations* of your original objects from inside PowerShell, you can use `Out-String`, which outputs the formatted representation as a single, multi-line string (unfortunately, with an extra trailing newline); when called from outside PowerShell, the effect will in essence be the same as calling `Out-Host`.

Note that in your case the workaround need only be applied to the `$testlist` statement:

```
# Or ... | Out-Host or ... | Format-Table - see comments above.
$testlist | Out-String
```

There's an **alternative, but more obscure workaround** that relies on  using `Start-Sleep` to wait at least 300 ms. *and outputting at least one more object after the implicit `Format-Table` call*, as demonstrated in this simplified example:

```
'before'
[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 }
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300  # wait for implicit Format-Table
'after' # force output of the table by outputting at least one more object
throw "error"
```

The **advantage** of this workaround is that **your original objects are preserved in the output this way**, which would allow you to capture them as such from inside PowerShell with, say,
`$output = try { ./someScript.ps1 } catch { Write-Error $_ }`

---

Finally, **your code can be streamlined**; to put it all together:

```
# Use *implicit* output - no need for Write-Output
# If you do use Write-Output: separate the arguments with *spaces*,
# don't put (...) around the argument list.
"test output 1"
# ...


# Implicitly capture the foreach loop output in an array.
# This is much more efficient than using += to "extend" an array
# in a loop (which requires creating a *new* array every time).
[array] $testlist = 
  foreach ($count in 1..6) {
    # Simpler and more efficient PSv3+ method for constructing
    # custom objects.
    [pscustomobject] @{ Name="array object $count" }
  }

# Apply the workaround.
$testlist | Out-String

# Use implicit output again.
"test output 6"
"test output 7"

throw "pretend error"
```

---

<sup>[1] That is, `throw` generates a *runspace*-terminating (script-terminating) error, which instantly aborts overall execution - unlike a *statement*-terminating error, which only aborts the statement at hand, such as would occur when an exception occurs in a .NET method call; You can convert all statement-terminating as well as all non-terminating errors to runspace-terminating ones by setting the `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable to `'Stop'` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @iRon, but it turns out that `Start-Sleep` works too (behaves the same as `Wait-Event -Timeout`, from what I can tell), but you need to output at least one additional object after it - please see my update.

Comment: Thankyou, this is very obscure, I never would have figured this out in a million years. 
If you are interested in context: I would definitely call this a bug because its very unexpected and had real-world consequences for me - checking the log of an important overnight job run, key info about things happening just before an error is missing because of this bug. Also the missing info makes it look like the error occured at a different point in the script. Erodes my trust in Powershell somewhat.

Comment: Further, if you want my opinion of the design decisions around the formatting delay: introducing an async delay seems like cheating. Like they have built in a delay and then tried to hide it under the carpet. If they really wanted to wait 300ms to sample data, that delay should occur synchronously. 
Many thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, the thing that caused the error in my script was a long running System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile() call - it ran for hours before failing. But because that command had started within 300ms of the implicit Format-Table, the Write-Output data was still lost.

Comment: @codeulike: Yes, if the _runspace_-terminating error exception happens during a command started within the 300-ms. window, irrespective of how long it runs before the exception occurred, control is never returned to PowerShell, and no output is produced. However, a .NET method call is by default only a _statement_-terminating error, which would _not_ produce the symptom - except if `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is in effect, which turns it into a _runspace_-terminating (script-terminating) one.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think maybe the circumstance was that someone stopped powershell.exe on the server, this led System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile() to throw an error message onto the log, and because powershell.exe was terminating that was it. So I guess I was lucky that when I made my script to reproduce the error I used 'throw'.

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. The way to ensure output is seen is the same way to ensure output is in the correct order when mixing `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` - use `Out-Host` after each line.

```
Write-Output ("test output 1") | Out-Host
Write-Output ("test output 2") | Out-Host
Write-Output ("test output 3") | Out-Host
Write-Output ("test output 4") | Out-Host
Write-Output ("test output 5") | Out-Host
$testlist = @()
$count = 1
While($count -lt 6)
{
    $testobj = new-object psobject -prop @{Name="array object $count"}
    $testlist += $testobj
    $count +=1
}
Write-Output $testlist  | Out-Host
Write-Output ("test output 6") | Out-Host
Write-Output ("test output 7") | Out-Host
throw "pretend error"
```

You could also enclose groups of lines in subexpression `$(..)` and do one `Out-Host` if that is suitable for the situation.

```
$(Write-Output ("test output 1")
Write-Output ("test output 2")
Write-Output ("test output 3")
Write-Output ("test output 4")
Write-Output ("test output 5")
$testlist = @()
$count = 1
While($count -lt 6)
{
    $testobj = new-object psobject -prop @{Name="array object $count"}
    $testlist += $testobj
    $count +=1
}
Write-Output $testlist
Write-Output ("test output 6")
Write-Output ("test output 7")) | Out-Host
throw "pretend error"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is baffling. Because according to the help "Out-Host is automatically appended to every command that is executed". It looks like if I just put Out-Host on the array output line, the rest are ok `Write-Output $testlist | Out-Host`

Comment: Ah, someone has an encylopedic explanation, I'll have to switch accepted answer, very sorry. You got there first!