# PowerShell ErrorRecord.CategoryInfo.Activity (CategoryActivity)

Tags: powershell, error-handling, standards

So PowerShell error reporting seems like a huge mess considering that there are four* ways to report an error (not including the effects of `$ErrorActionPreference`, `try/catch`, and `trap` blocks which have the potential to alter how an error is reported by another source), with minute and poorly documented differences, and even worse there's no real instruction on when to use the different types. (I realize it varies on the situation, but what's the "standard" - what will others be expecting me to do?)

That's not really the main point here though. I've decided to go with the simplest option when possible as that's what I expect most others will be using, so at least we'll have consistency - but I'm either not understanding something properly or it's broken.

According to the [PowerShell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorcategoryinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#properties), the `Activity` property of `ErrorCategoryInfo` class (observed in the `CategoryInfo` property of `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`) should be a "text description of the operation which encountered the error". Considering the fact that the value is settable and (in the case of compiled cmdlets) indicates the name of the cmdlet unless otherwise specified, I would expect the same functionality in script-based error reporting methods, but I'm doing something wrong or I've found a bug in PowerShell that has pervaded since PowerShell 1.0.

Consider the following example:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation;
function Invoke-Error1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param() 
    process {
        $ex = [InvalidOperationException]::new()
        $er = [ErrorRecord]::new($ex, 'OperationTest', [ErrorCategory]::InvalidOperation, 'MyErrorTarget')
        $er.CategoryInfo.Activity = 'MyActivity'
        Write-Error -ErrorRecord $er
    }
}
```

Invoking this function will result in the following error.

```
invoke-error1 : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-error1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MyErrorTarget:String) [Write-Error], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationTest,Invoke-Error1
```

When investigating further, you'll notice that the `CategoryInfo.Activity` property has been replaced by `Write-Error`. The value I set ("MyActivity") is ignored. If this were expected, I wouldn't expect a parameter on the Write-Error method to set the error category - and yet one seems to exist. (See `Get-Help Write-Error -Parameter CategoryActivity`. I can't see anything else that this might be intended to do.)

This can be confirmed through the following function.

```
function Invoke-Error2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param() 
    process {
        $Params = @{
            Exception         = [InvalidOperationException]::new()
            ErrorId           = 'OperationTest'
            Category          = [ErrorCategory]::InvalidOperation
            TargetObject      = 'MyErrorTarget'
            CategoryActivity  = 'MyActivity'
        }
        Write-Error @Params
    }
}
```

The error reported is identical in all ways to the error from `Invoke-Error1` aside from the name of the cmdlet and associated InvocationInfo. Specifically, note again that `$Error[0].CategoryInfo.Activity -eq 'Write-Error'` instead of "MyActivity".

And yet, there is a way to write an error that *does* properly write the error activity with the error... but it seems to be the lowest on the list of recommended ways to report an error since it's *generally* the same as Write-Error.

```
function Invoke-Error3 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    process {
    $ex = [InvalidOperationException]::new()
        $er = [ErrorRecord]::new($ex, 'OperationTest', [ErrorCategory]::InvalidOperation, 'MyErrorTarget')
        $er.CategoryInfo.Activity = 'MyActivity'
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($er)
    }
}
```

This function is identical in all ways to `Invoke-Error1` except that I use `$PSCmdlet.WriteError` instead of `Write-Error`. According to [certain community standards](https://poshcode.gitbook.io/powershell-practice-and-style/best-practices/performance), it's preferred to use built-in functions over .NET calls, though of course when behavior differs it makes sense to use the procedure that produces the desired result.

This is the most similar method to how any compiled cmdlet writes an error. As a result, any error written by a cmdlet will use either a manually set `Activity` value, or use the default of the cmdlet's name. I believe the latter of these is somehow what's happening with `Write-Error`.

That being said, I can't feel like I'm missing something here. The `CategoryInfo` property and associated `CategoryActivity` parameter of `Write-Error` have existed since PowerShell 1.0. Certainly if this functionality never worked someone would have noticed by now? So what am I doing wrong? How would I properly report the error? Going back to the purpose of the `Activity` property of `ErrorCategoryInfo`, "Write-Error" is not the operation that encountered the error - my function did, and I want to report it *using* `Write-Error`. Is this possible?

---

*If you aren't aware, the errors that can be reported from a PowerShell script or script function are the following:

- Script-Terminating (via `throw`)
- Statement-Terminating (via `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError`)
- Non-Terminating Error (via `Write-Error`)
- Non-Terminating Error (via `$PSCmdlet.WriteError`). This is much harder to distinguish from `Write-Error` but does behave differently - note this question, and the fact that `$ErrorActionPreference` does not affect the behavior of an error emitted directly by `$PSCmdlet.WriteError` (though `$ErrorActionPreference` will affect behavior of an error emitted *indirectly* from `$PSCmdlet.WriteError` if the *direct* source is a script). This can be tested by setting `$ErrorActionPreference` inside your function that proceeds to call `$PSCmdlet.WriteError` vs `Write-Error`.
- In addition to these methods, any non-terminating error can be turned into a statement-terminating error via `$ErrorActionPreference` or the `-ErrorAction` common parameter. The `$?` variable can be used in error reporting but seems like a terrible way to do so based on how much the result of that variable varies. `try/catch` blocks can be used to catch errors and access them through the `$PSItem` variable, but within that block if you're executing from a function defined in a module you may or may not see the error through `$Error` depending on whether or not the command that reported the error is defined in your module. Writing a permeation of a caught exception may yield two errors being added to the `$global:Error` variable - the caught exception that I'd expect to be ignored will be placed in `$global:Error` if the command that caught it is defined in a module other than the one the error was thrown from, and the new error that I reported.

Comment: Considering the nuance-oriented investigation you are performing, I feel somewhat unworthy of this topic, but have you looked at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.1) for some further details or lines of investigation?

Comment: @Darrell I appreciate the suggestion. I have read through that article - in fact, it points out some of the inconsistencies with errors in PowerShell (though I'll note it also misses a few and conflates a few), but doesn't really mention the CategoryAction at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, kudos for your in-depth analysis.

You've already found an effective workaround *that also works in Windows PowerShell* for having your custom `.Activity` value honored: use of [`$PSCmdlet.WriteError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteError) - though note that `$PSCmdlet` is only available in [*advanced* functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) and scripts.

That an `.Activity` value *isn't* honored if it is part of a [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instance passed in full to [`Write-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error)'s `-ErrorRecord` parameter, whereas it now *is* if you use the `-CategoryActivity` parameter (shorter alias: `-Activity`) *in PowerShell (Core)7+*, is arguably a *bug* that I encourage you to report at the [PowerShell GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues).

- *Update*: Thankfully, you have since done so in [GitHub issue #15088](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15088).

Note: As you point out, the following **alternative workarounds** are **effective in *PowerShell (Core) 7+ only***:

A slightly **less obscure workaround** that doesn't require `$PSCmdlet` and is therefore also available in *non*-advanced functions and scripts:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation

$ex = [InvalidOperationException]::new()
$er = [ErrorRecord]::new($ex, 'OperationTest', [ErrorCategory]::InvalidOperation, 'MyErrorTarget')
$er.CategoryInfo.Activity = 'MyActivity'

# Workaround: Specify the activity *also* via -Activity
Write-Error -ErrorRecord $er -Activity $er.CategoryInfo.Activity
```

Note: To see a friendly representation of the resulting error (record), pipe the above to
`2>&1 | Format-List -Force`; in PowerShell (Core) 7+, you can alternatively use the dedicated [`Get-Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error) cmdlet.

Alternatively, you can **bypass the *explicit* construction of `[ErrorRecord]` altogether** and use a combination of different parameters to achieve the same result:

```
Write-Error -Exception InvalidOperationException `
            -ErrorId OperationTest `
            -Activity MyActivity `
            -TargetObject MyErrorTarget
```

---

> I've found a bug in PowerShell that has pervaded since PowerShell 1.0.

It looks like it.

The likeliest explanation is that *direct* construction of [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) *in PowerShell code* requires advanced knowledge and is rare - in fact, *letting `Write-Error` construct such an instance* for you is its primary purpose, offering the familiar command-line experience of a cmdlet with *parameters*, as shown in the last workaround above.

Another factor is probably that few callers that *handle* error records pay attention to fields such as `.CategoryInfo.Activity`; typically, it is the `.ErrorId` field or the wrapped exception's .NET type that is considered.
On a more philosophical note, one could argue that the `ErrorRecord` type is a bit over-engineered.

---

As for your more general observation:

> there's no real instruction on when to use the different types [of errors]

- GitHub documentations issue [Our Error Handing, Ourselves - time to fully understand and properly document PowerShell's error handling](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) aims to provide an overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex and partially inconsistent error handling and asks that such an overview become an official part of the documentation.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) attempts to provide guidance as to when to use *non-terminating* vs. *statement-terminating* errors.

  - That there are *two* types of *terminating* errors - *script*-terminating (fatal) vs. *statement*-terminating, and that `throw` in *PowerShell code* only ever creates the *former*, whereas `.ThrowTerminatingError()` (typically only used in C# code) only ever creates the latter is a confusing asymmetry - [this comment on GitHub issue #14819](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14819#issuecomment-786114099) makes the case for abandoning this distinction in favor of offering *only* *script*-terminating errors in a future PowerShell version - i.e. the only kind of terminating error would then be one that is *fatal* by default. Doing so would:

    - prevent further commands in a script from executing by default, which seems called for, given that what are currently statement-terminating errors are usually *severe* error conditions.
    - eliminate the confusing asymmetry between the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#erroraction) having *no* effect on statement-terminating errors, whereas [preference variable `$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference), when set to `'Stop'`, does (promotes them to *script*-terminating errors).

Comment: I appreciate the response. IMO if it reports an error, it should use CmdletBinding, so I didn't consider the inability to use $PSCmdlet. One thing I'd like to point out is the `Write-Error -CategoryAction` method (see `Invoke-Error2`) in my example (which uses Windows PowerShell) ignores the `CategoryAction` parameter, hence the proposed solution would not work in the example case. Your solution is viable in PowerShell Core indicating `-CategoryAction`'s functionality is a bug in Windows PowerShell that was later fixed, but this is why I reverted to using `[ErrorRecord]` in the first place.

Comment: And indeed, I was reading through those same two documents on PowerShell errors earlier today again. I can't imagine the implications of turning all statement-terminating errors into script-terminating in existing code, but ... I suppose that's pretty much how I handle everything internally ($ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' inside every function except where I'm reporting an error), so maybe I could live with it :).

Comment: Thanks, good point that the alternative workarounds require PS Core - I've updated the answer to note that. That still leaves the bug of the `ErrorRecord`-supplied category not getting honored, which should be fixed.

Comment: As for getting rid of statement-terminating errors: this would have to be an _opt-in_ basis to avoid a massively breaking change. We have a similar situation on our hand with respect to finally fixing the broken argument-passing to external programs, which is now being considered in [GitHub issue #14747](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14747). Taking a step back: a lot of historical baggage has accumulated over the years due to PowerShell's steadfast commitment to backward compatibility, which is discussed in [issue #6745](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6745).