# How to properly write a C# error to powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

Let's say I have the following block:

```cs
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
  try
  {
    // code that throws
  }
  catch (System.Exception exception)
  {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

How can I properly write the exception? Using `WriteError`? Is the following a good approach?

```cs
WriteError(new ErrorRecord(exception, exception.Source, ErrorCategory.InvalidOperation, exception));
```

If so, should I be using `ErrorRecord`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need an [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instance to report an error from a PowerShell cmdlet.

What method you use to report the error depends on whether you want it to be a *terminating* or, more typically, a *non-terminating* error:

- *non-terminating* errors are reported via the [`System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.WriteError) method
- (statement-)*terminating* errors are reported via the [`System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError) method

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375) for guidance on when to report which type of error.

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
WriteError(
  new ErrorRecord(
   exception,                      // parameter: exception
   exception.Source,               // errorId
   ErrorCategory.InvalidOperation, // category
   exception)                      // targetObject
);
```

- You're passing the [`.Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Exception.Source) property value of your exception to parameter `errorId`, but this parameter isn't meant to contain the originating *application*, but a (freely chosen) string identifying the *type* of error, such as `PathNotFound`, to which PowerShell automatically adds source information (the name of the originating command) and exposes it via the `.FullyQualifiedErrorId` property.
- You're passing `exception` twice, but the last parameter, [`targetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.-ctor#System_Management_Automation_ErrorRecord__ctor_System_Exception_System_String_System_Management_Automation_ErrorCategory_System_Object_), isn't meant to refer to an exception, but to *the object during whose processing the error occurred*.