# Powershell: terminating exception still continues to next command

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I was expecting that with a terminating exception, the script execution will hault in powershell.

Since try/catch will only capture terminating exception(other than ErroActionPreference etc)
I had the below code

```
try {

$hashtableJson = "asdfg.kjhgf" | ConvertFrom-Json
} catch {
       Write-Host "inside catch block"
}
```

and I can see "inside catch block" printed.
Which means the exception `System.ArgumentException` which comes due to invalid json is terminating.
Now my doubt is in the below script

```
$hashtableJson = "asdfg.kjhgf" | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host "after terminating"
```

In the above script I expected the run to break on the first line itself but the `after terminating` still gets printed.

Any explanation why its not exiting the flow? or how to better figure out if exception is terminating or not?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the unexpected behavior you describe. How are you executing the statements? Are you pasting them into a terminal? If so, the host application might be simply executing them as two separate statements...

Comment: I can reproduce it with v5.1. with a .ps1 file. My `$ErrorActionPreference` is `Continue`.

Comment: What makes you think the cmdlet would produce a terminating error? You need to set your error preference to `Stop` for that. At most it would produce an error that would stop the pipeline.

Comment: Because in the first example it falls into the catch block without setting any ErrorActionPreference. ALso, ErrorActionPreference by default is continue which implies(acc to me) by first case it should be terminating. and try/catch doesn't capture non-terminating

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The about_Try_Catch_Finally docs talk only about terminating errors.

Comment: @SonaliGupta the fact that the script "continues" or is not halting after the error implies that the error is only terminating for that pipeline not for the script itself. A terminating error would stop the script no matter what your Error Preference is (which is not something you would see often for a cmdlet)

Comment: @mklement0 I agree re the docs not giving the full scope of the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell has ***two* types of *terminating errors***, which **the documentation currently *conflates***, unfortunately:

- ***Statement*-terminating** errors, as reported by compiled cmdlets (as opposed to written-in-PowerShell [advanced functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced))<sup>[1]</sup> and .NET methods, which only terminate the current *statement* by default; that is, **by default execution of the script *continues***, with the next statement.
- ***Script*-terminating** (runspace-terminating, **fatal**) errors, as raised by `throw` and when `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is in effect or when `-ErrorAction Stop` is passed to cmdlets and advanced functions / scripts and a *non*-terminating error occurs.

The third error type - the most common one - is a ***non*-terminating error**, which doesn't affect the control flow at all: by default even processing of the current statement (with remaining pipeline input) continues. As for when cmdlets are expected to use non-terminating vs. terminating errors, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).

Note:

- Arguably, there should only ever have been *one* type of terminating error: *script*-terminating (fatal), which, if needed, could be *handled as* merely statement-terminating, with `try` / `catch` (see below), but it's too late to change that.
- For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling, see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

---

[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), as a compiled cmdlet, emits a *statement*-terminating error when invalid JSON is provided as input, which explains why execution of your script continues.

You can use **[`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) or [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) to catch *both* statement- and script-terminating errors** - but **not *non-terminating* ones** by default, **unless you promote them to script-terminating ones with `-ErrorAction Stop`**.

By contrast, **`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` promotes *all* errors to script-terminating (fatal) ones, including *non*-terminating ones**.

Note:

- In the *absence* of `try` / `catch` and `trap`, passing `-ErrorAction Stop` to an individual cmdlet does *not* promote a *statement*-terminating error to a *script*-terminating one, which means that execution *continues with the next statement* in that case.
- This confusing asymmetry - `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` acting on *all* errors to make them fatal vs. `-ErrorAction Stop` only acting on *non-terminating* errors - is the subject of [GitHub issue #14819](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14819).

The upshot:

- To **treat *all* errors occurring in your scope - including *non*-terminating ones - as fatal**, use `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

```bash
# Treat *all* errors in this scope (and descendant scopes)
# as *script*-terminating (fatal).
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Trigger a *non*-terminating error, which is *also* promoted
# to a script-terminating one.
Get-Item NoSuchFile 

# Trigger a *statement*-terminating error, which is promoted
# to a script-terminating one.
# Note: Because of the Get-Item error, this statement isn't reached, 
#       Comment it out to see that this statement too causes a
#       script-terminating error.
$hashtableJson = "asdfg.kjhgf" | ConvertFrom-Json

'This statement is now never reached.'
```

- By contrast, use the following techniques to **make only *terminating* errors fatal *while keeping non-terminating errors non-terminating***:

  - Scope-wide, you can use the (rarely used) **[`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement** to that effect, namely by placing `trap { break }` in your scope:

```bash
# Trap both kinds of *terminating* errors and abort.
trap { break }

# Trigger a *non*-terminating error, which is left alone (not
# caught by the trap).
Get-Item NoSuchFile 

# Trigger a *statement*-terminating error, which triggers the trap.
$hashtableJson = "asdfg.kjhgf" | ConvertFrom-Json

'This statement is now never reached.'
```

- Alternatively, especially if you need you more *fine-grained* control, **use `try` / `catch`** around statements of interest and **use `throw` from the `catch` block** to trigger a *script*-terminating error.

```bash
try {

  # Trigger a *non*-terminating error, which is left alone (does
  # not trigger the catch block).
  Get-Item NoSuchFile 

  # Trigger a *statement*-terminating error, which triggers the catch block.
  $hashtableJson = "asdfg.kjhgf" | ConvertFrom-Json

} catch {
  throw # Re-throw the *statement*-terminating error as *script*-terminating.
}

'This statement is now never reached.'
```

---

<sup>[1] It *is* possible to make an advanced function / script emit a *statement*-terminating error, namely via `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`, but that is both obscure and cumbersome; in practice, it is far more common to use the *script*-terminating `throw` statement.</sup>

Comment: So between command terminating exception versus non-terminating exception, the main difference(benefit) would be that we can try/catch the first but not the second without setting the ErrorActionPreference. Rest both of them allow a script to move on and hence arent that different?

Comment: @SonaliGupta, note that .NET exceptions only underly the _terminating_ errors in PowerShell, so calling non-terminating errors exception isn't strictly correct). Non-terminating errors are reported for individual input objects from the pipeline, and processing continues with further input objects. Unlike terminating errors, you can suppress non-terminating errors with `-ErrorAction Ignore` or `2>$null`, and you can _collect_ them with `-ErrorVariable`. More details about how non-terminating vs. terminating errors differ are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375).

Answer (score 1):

I think either the documentation of `$ErrorActionPreference` or the error classification of PS is wrong, but when I have `Continue` then I can reproduce the above, but setting it to `Stop`, "after terminating" is no longer popping up (tested for v5.1. with a .ps1 file).

Comment: What the docs don't mention: there are _statement_-terminating and there are _script_-terminating errors. Cmdlets emit only the former (though more typically emit _non_-terminating errors). `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` promotes both statement-terminating and non-terminating errors to _script_-terminating ones. See the comments on the question for more information.