# Assignment of version-like value (numbers with two or more dots) in Powershell

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, powershell-core

Recently I discovered some nasty behavior about assigning some version-like value to variable in Powershell (at least in 7.2.5).

At first I tried:

```
> $version = 1.2.3
> echo $version
```

I quickly found out that I have to escape thr value with quotes to make it string explicitly. This one works well:

```
> $version = "1.2.3"
> echo $version
1.2.3
```

The question is: *Why* does it work this way? Why does `pwsh` not throw some kind of error in the first example and just converts it to `$null`? Like in other cases:

```
> 12a
12a: The term '12a' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

> [int]12a
ParserError:
Line |
   1 |  [int]12a
     |       ~~~
     | Unexpected token '12a' in expression or statement.
```

So I believe literals like `1.2.3` *are* expected and managed by some rule.
I tried to dig into documentation about [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-07?view=powershell-7.2) and [assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.2), but can't find the correct answer.

Comment: You will found out soon if you do this `Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0` before this `1.2.3` :)

Comment: it may even surprise you that something like this is possible too: `$version = 1.2; $version.PSObject.Properties.Add([psnoteproperty]::new(3, 'hello!')); $version.3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *why* it works this way?

In effect, `1.2.3` is parsed as `(1.2).3`, i.e. as *number literal* `1.2` whose `.3` *property* is retrieved.

Number literal `1.2` is an instance of a `[double]` ([`System.Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Double), a double-precision floating point value), and as such has *no* `.3` property (or any other property).

By default, PowerShell quietly returns `$null` when you try to access a non-existent property on an object.

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, you can turn such attempts into (statement-terminating) *errors* if you use [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 2` or higher:

```bash
PS> Set-StrictMode -Version 2; 1.2.3
... The property '3' cannot be found on this object. ...
```

Note:

- A given strict mode takes effect for the entire scope and any descendant scopes.

  - Note that this can make calling scripts or non-module functions fail, if they weren't designed with this strict mode in mind (it is common for code to assume that *no* strict mode is in effect).
  - To turn an active strict mode *off*, use `Set-StrictMode -Off`
- Due to a long-standing bug - see [GitHub issue #2798](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2798) and [#16427](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16427) - the [intrinsic members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) `.Count` and `.Length` - useful for unified handling of collections and scalars - are then not available.
- The fact that strict mode version 2 or higher causes a *statement*-terminating error for attempts to access a non-existent property means that *execution continues by default*, with the next statement.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72802148/45375) for how to make such errors *script*-terminating errors, i.e. *fatal* ones.
- See [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron)'s comment below for links to GitHub issues discussing the perhaps surprising behavior at hand (`1.2.3` quietly evaluating to `$null`), as well as a link to a suggestion to implement a [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) rule that would warn about expressions such as `1.2.3`, so that you'd get a *design-time* warning when editing code in Visual Studio Code, for instance.

---

Finally, if you want to create `1.2.3` as a *version object*, you can cast from a string:

- `[version] '1.2.3'` to create a [`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version) instance.
- *PowerShell (Core) 7+ only*: `[semver] '1.2.3'` to create a [`System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion) instance.

Comment: The issue itself is (also) described in: [`#15756` Unquoted numbers with two or more dots should cast to a **version** rather than `$Null`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15756) and duplicate: [#15909 `$a = 1.2.3` gives no error message but doesn't do anything](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15909) and requested as PSScriptAnalyzer rule: [`#1698` Rule request: Warn when second dot on numeric literal causes member access expression](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1698)

Comment: Thanks, @iRon. I've updated the answer to point to your comment.