# Why does AWS Tools for Powershell ignore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-powershell

I want to get `$null` from the `Get-IAMUser` command in case the user does not exist.

I investigated using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` but it seems to be ignored.

```
Line |
   3 |  if ($null -ne (Get-IAMUser -UserName SomeUserName))
     |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The user with name SomeUserName cannot be found.
```

Is there a way to get rid of this error message?

Comment: Does `Get-IAMUser` accept `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`? Or is it a terminating error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately, AWS Powershell modules heavily use *terminating* errors instead of *non-terminating errors*.**

If they used non-terminating errors, we'd be able to use [`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.4#-erroraction) to suppress the error message and continue with executing the script. However, passing `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to AWS Powershell cmdlets usually has no effect and is 'ignored'.

The error is a terminating error so use [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.4) instead.

---

Recommended approach:

```
$userName = 'random-string'

try {
    $iamUser = Get-IAMUser -UserName $userName
    Write-Host "User '$userName' exists."
} catch {
    Write-Host "User '$userName' does not exist."
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to really use `if ($null -ne $iamUser)`:

```
$userName = 'random-string'

try {
    $iamUser = Get-IAMUser -UserName $userName
} catch {
    # will re-throw the exception if it does not relate to the "user not found" scenario
    if ($_.Exception.InnerException.ErrorCode -eq "NoSuchEntity") {
        $iamUser = $null
    } else {
        throw
    }
}

if ($null -ne $iamUser) {
    Write-Host "User '$userName' exists."
} else {
    Write-Host "User '$userName' does not exist."
}
```

Output:

```bash
User 'random-string' does not exist.
```

---

Note that most PowerShell `Get-*` commands don't throw terminating errors, and so there is currently an [open feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/331) that hopefully is addressed in a future update...

Comment: Good background info, and I'm glad to see that a change may be coming (although it would be a substantially breaking one). One thing worth considering: To make your sample code future-proof, add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Get-IAMUser` calls.
Otherwise, should the errors become non-terminating in the future, the `catch` block would no longer be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [Ermiya Eskandary's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634900/45375):

An alternative approach is to take advantage of the - surprising - fact that [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) *does* act on *terminating* errors too.
If you set it in a *child scope* and call the cmdlet from there - via `& { ... }` - the change is implicitly limited to that scope, so there's no need to restore the previous setting:

```bash
$iamUser = 
  & { $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Get-IAMUser -UserName $userName }
```

Note:

- If `Get-IAMUser` fails, `$iamUser` receives the "enumerable null", i.e. the special `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton that signifies "no pipeline output"; however in *expression contexts* this value behaves like `$null`, so that `$null -eq $iamUser` works correctly.

  - Also, the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) will *not* reflect `$false` afterwards in case an error occurred inside the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) (it only does while *inside* the script block).
  - If the call fails, you'll have to examine the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error) to identify the *specific error* (exception) that occurred, e.g. with `$Error[0].Exception`.

    - However, if you do need this, the [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) approach may be more convenient, as you note, as it allows you to define [exception-specific `catch` blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally#using-multiple-catch-statements).
- Even if the AWS cmdlets get fixed to emit *non-terminating* errors<sup>[1]</sup> - which *can* be silenced with the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) - the awkward asymmetry between `-ErrorAction` and the *seemingly* equivalent `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable (which acts on *all* errors) will remain.

  - [GitHub issue #14819](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14819) discusses this inconsistency.
  - For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's bewilderingly complex error handling, see [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

---

<sup>[1] For guidance on when cmdlets should emit *non-terminating* vs. *(statement-)terminating errors*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39949027/45375). Note that non-terminating errors are much more common.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for detailed information and explanation! Still, thinks the 'try..catch' way is better than your 'one-liner' as it's possible to handle different exceptions, like missing permissions.

Comment: That's a good point, @Kamarey; with the approach here you'd have to examine `$Error[0]` afterwards to identify the specific exception. I've updated the answer to make that clear.