# Is it possible to configure $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' as the default for all the functions in a powershell module?

Tags: powershell, module

I want all of the functions in my module to default to `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. Is it possible without modifying all the functions?

I have a file per function.

Comment: Have you tried using ```[CmdletBinding()]``` and just running the function with ```-ErrorAction Stop```? This would give you the behavior you are looking for, without doing any adjusting of the global variable ```$ErrorActionPreference```? As mentioned here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950760/emulating-erroraction-in-custom-powershell-function or here on Microsoft Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-6 -- either way, CmdletBinding autoenables additional params

Comment: I do not want to depend on this behaviour having been set externally when the command is run. I want it to be the default  for my functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Assuming that your module is a *script* module, i.e., implemented in PowerShell code:**

**Important**:

- Modules have their own stack of scopes that is independent of the scopes of non-module code (and other modules'). While this provides isolation from the caller's environment that is generally useful, it also means that **the *caller's* `$ErrorActionPreference` value *never* takes effect for script-module functions** (unless you directly run from the *global* scope, which modules also see) - but it *does* take effect for *binary (compiled) cmdlets*. This highly problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).
- Even though you therefore currently cannot control a script module's error behavior from the *caller* by way of `$ErrorActionPreference`, by setting (overriding) `$ErrorActionPreference` *in your module* you're closing that door permanently.
- However, using **the `-ErrorAction` *common parameter*** for a specific call instead of the `$ErrorActionPreference` *preference variable* **will still override your module-global `$ErrorActionPreference`** value, because, behind the scenes, PowerShell translates the `-ErrorAction` argument to a *function-local* `$ErrorActionPreference` variable with that value.
- The `-ErrorAction` and `$ErrorActionPreference` mechanisms are plagued by inconsistencies and obscure behaviors - [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) provides a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling.

> I want all of the functions in my module to default to `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. Is it possible without modifying all the functions?

Yes - simply place `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` in your `RootModule` `*.psm1` file's top-level code. (The `RootModule` entry of a module's manifest file (`*.psd1`) specifies a module's main module - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest)).

- If you don't have a `RootModule` entry that references a `.psm1` file, simply create a `.psm1` file in your module folder (typically named for the enclosing module) with content `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, and reference it from the `RootModule` entry - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55882472/45375) for background information.

Unless overridden by the caller by using the common `-ErrorAction` parameter when calling your module's functions (assuming they are *advanced* functions), your module's top-level `$ErrorActionPreference` value will be in effect for all of your module's functions, *except* if your function *directly* emits a *statement*-terminating error<sup>[1]</sup>, in which case it is the *caller's* `$ErrorActionPreference` value that matters.

---

**If your module is a *binary* module, i.e., exports *compiled cmdlets* (typically implemented in C#):**

Compiled cmdlets don't have their own scope - they run in the *caller's* scope. It is therefore the *caller's* `$ErrorActionPreference` that matters, which can be overridden on a per-call basis with common parameter `-ErrorAction`, but only for *non*-terminating errors.

As with advanced functions in script modules, directly emitted *statement*-terminating errors<sup>[1]</sup> are *always* subject to the caller's `$ErrorActionPreference` value, even if `-ErrorAction` is used. (Note that binary cmdlets do not emit *script*-terminating errors).

---

[1] *Statement*-terminating errors occur in the following scenarios:

- *Directly*, to abort execution of the enclosing cmdlet or advanced function/script:

  - When a binary *cmdlet* encounters a severe error that prevents it from continuing, it reports such an error with the [`ThrowTerminatingError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.throwterminatingerror) method (or just throws an exception).
  - An advanced PowerShell function/script would similarly have to use `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()`, which, however, is rare in practice; the typically used `Throw` statement creates a *script*-terminating (fatal) error instead, which by default also terminates the entire runspace (thread), i.e., also terminates the caller and all its callers.
- *Indirectly*, in PowerShell code:

  - When an *expression* causes a *runtime* error, such as `1 / 0` or `'a,b' -split ',', 'NotAnInt'`.
  - When a .NET *method call* throws an exception, such as `[int]::Parse('NotAnInt')`
  - When, inside an advanced function/script, another cmdlet or advanced function / script is called that itself directly emits a statement-terminating error.
  - Note that advanced functions/scripts cannot *relay* statement-terminating errors *as such*:

    - By default (with `$ErrorActionPreference` containing `'Continue'`, possibly just in the local scope) the expression's / other command's terminating error effectively becomes a *non*-terminating error from the caller's perspective.
    - With `$ErrorActionPreference` set to `'Stop'`, the originally statement-terminating error is promoted to a *script*-terminating error.

Comment: *"unless you directly run from the global scope, which modules also see"* - even if you aren't running from the global scope (typically you'd be running from script scope), you could simply set `$Global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`. In fact this has been suggested in the GitHub issue you linked to: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568#issuecomment-364140304.

Comment: @OhadSchneider, yes, but (a) this question is about scoping the preference _to a given module_ and (b) setting `$ErrorActionPreference` globally _from code_ is definitely ill-advised; if it can't be avoided, it must be set _temporarily_, and restored in a guaranteed manner via the `finally` block of a `try / catch / finally` statement.

Comment: ill-advised because dependent modules might rely on the non-modified global `$ErrorActionPreference` default value (namely `Continue`)?

Comment: @OhadSchneider, it's not so much what settings  other code relies on, it's about - as a given piece of code - not unilaterally changing the session's behavior globally (only the interactive user should make such decisions).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do this with explicit default parameter setting in the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-6) session-wide [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6).

This includes the ability to set the **ErrorAction** [Common Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6) default for specific functions. Keep in mind, you would want to *append* the current value of `$PSDefaultParameterValues` since it uses a hash table, and other functions may currently have defaults set in the current session. This would also mean that [`[CmdletBinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-6) needs to be included in every function that is being given this default value.

`$PSDefaultParameterValues` is a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6), so you would want to modify in a fashion like so:

```bsh
$PSDefaultParameterValues += @{
    "Get-Function:ErrorAction"="Stop"
    "Get-Command:ErrorAction"="Stop"
    "Get-MyFunction*:ErrorAction"="Stop"
}
```

or

```bsh
$PSDefaultParameterValues.add("Get-Function:ErrorAction","Stop")
```

[Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6) are accepted in function/cmdlet names, which may make it easier to get all of your functions in one line if you have a unique noun prefix naming scheme for imports from your module (though, this would include any other functions/cmdlets if any are imported into a session that include the same naming prefix).

Comment: This seems to belong to the profile script, which is not a good idea. I want it to be the feature of the module - every function in it runs with EA = 'Stop' as the default.