# Script calling Get-Volume does not throw an exception although ErrorActionPreference is set to "Stop"

Tags: powershell

This is my script in file `test.ps1`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" # make it throw an exception
try
{
  Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel "doesnotexist"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.Cim.CimJobException]
{
  Write-Host "exception thrown"
}
```

I run it from a PowerShell terminal like this:

```
./test.ps1
```

But it does not throw the exception and instead prints out a red error message.

If you're familiar with PowerShell you will understand that it should throw an exception instead.

Why doesn't it throw an exception as expected?

Comment: It looks like the reason is that `Get-Volume` is implemented as a script function, rather than a compiled cmdlet, in Windows PowerShell. There is a known issue with cmdlets implemented as script functions - preference variables like `$ErrorActionPreference` are not respected by default, unless they are global variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55841499/7571258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do one of the following:

- Set `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` before calling the script
- Use `$Global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` in the script
- Execute the script as `powershell.exe -file test.ps1`
- Use `Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel "notreal" -ErrorAction Stop` in the script

Answer (score 1):

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) has provided the crucial pointer:

- The [`Get-Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume) command is implemented as a *function* that is part of the `Storage` module, which is a ([CDXML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/cdxml-overview)-based) [*script* module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/understanding-a-windows-powershell-module#script-modules), i.e. implemented *in PowerShell code*.
- **Due to an unfortunate design limitation** - see [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568) - **module-based functions do NOT see the [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) of outside callers** - they only see such variables if they're defined in the *global* scope (which is the only scope that modules and non-module code share).

  - Note: *Binary* cmdlets - i.e. those implemented as .NET assemblies (typically compiled from C# code) - are *not* affected.
- Therefore, **your script-scoped `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` definition had *no effect***.

---

**Workarounds:**

- [Suboptimal]: Set `$ErrorActionPreference` in the *global* scope:

  - `$global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`
  - Important: Given that global definitions apply *session-wide* and *linger* after your script exits, be sure to restore the *previous* value of `$global:ErrorActionPreference` before exiting your script.
- Preferably, **use the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction)** with `Get-Volume`, which is a *command-scoped* way of setting `$ErrorActionPreference`, which module-based functions honor as well.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
try
{
  # -ErrorAction Stop promotes the *non-terminating* error that Get-Volume
  # emits to a (script)-*terminating* one, which triggers the `catch` block.
  Get-Volume -ErrorAction Stop -FileSystemLabel "doesnotexist"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.Cim.CimJobException]
{
  Write-Host "exception thrown"
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Behind the scenes, when `-ErrorAction` is used with an (of necessity [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)) function - whether module-based or not - PowerShell translates the value into a *function-local* `$ErrorActionPreference` variable.

Even though this should be a mere *implementation detail*, it can unfortunately have side effects - see [GitHub issue #19500](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19500).</sup>